# Examples on scalar distance field or directed distance field?

Tags: graphics, glsl, shader, modeling

I come across the scalar distance field and directed distance field in this paper Feature Sensitive Surface Extraction from Volume Data.

What is the difference and can anyone provide an example. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The application of the method from this [paper](https://www.graphics.rwth-aachen.de/media/papers/feature1.pdf) can be seen in the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDxKm_7PZmA)

Answer (score 0):

from http://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/distfunctions/distfunctions.htm

I figured it out...

### directed distance will be

If a Sphere is defined as follow

```
float sdSphere( vec3 p, float s )
{
    return length(p)-s;
}
```

Given any point

```
vec3 a
```

in the space, The directed distance will has direction

```
a - p
```

with signed distance

```
sdSphere(a, s)
```

### scalar distance will be

```
Sphere - signed - exact

float sdSphere( vec3 p, float s )
{
    return length(p)-s;
}

Sphere - unsigned - exact

float sdSphere( vec3 p, float s )
{
  return abs(length(p)-s);
}
```

Comment: You're mixing things up here, the signed aswell as unsigned distance fields you're referring here are **both** *scalar* distance fields.

Comment: Directed distance fields as described in the paper preserve the spatial distance information by not doing the `R³ => R` mapping.